# Removing padding from seekbar

Tags: android, padding, android-seekbar

Is there a way to remove the padding that is in the default android seekbar, such that there is no space above or below the seekbar?

I have tried setting the padding to 0 but all that does is remove the padding on either side of the padding.

Comment: Is your Seekbar in a RelativeLayout (or other layout)?

Comment: I've tried with both a RelativeLayout and a LinearLayout

Comment: Try setting the padding **of the layout** to 0dp, in addition to the Seekbar.